# Unable to use {0} in ContentStringFormat as the first character

Tags: wpf, xaml, label

I'd like to dynamically insert value in Label Content, it easily solves by ContentStringFormat, f.e. :

```
 <Label
    Content="{Binding ElementName=recipesDataGrid, Path=Items.Count}"
    ContentStringFormat="recipe(s) found: {0}"/>
```

But when I want to place {0} at the beginning of the ContentStringFormat, I receive errors:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [escape the curly braces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension) with `{}`, otherwise they will be interpreted as markup extension.

> Provides the XAML escape sequence for attribute values. The escape sequence allows the subsequent values in the attribute to be interpreted as a literal.

Adapt your content format string by adding `{}` at the beginning.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=recipesDataGrid, Path=Items.Count}"
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0} recipe(s) found" />
```